# Is it possible to remove permissions from an Android application?

Tags: android, permissions

I am new to Android. I've been looking for a way to remove a permission of other app. For example, I don't want an app to send SMS. Is it possible?
Thanx in advance.

---

Thanx for the replies.

Actually, I am in middle of coding where I want to restrict the manifest permission of other application.

Since, these kind of applications exist in market, then this is possible. Any more help or any reference would be so helpful.

thanx again.

Comment: This question probably belongs on [Android.SE].

Comment: You may be interested in [AppFence](http://appfence.org/).

Answer (score 5):

You need to be rooted for that, and there are already programs on the market that allow you to do it, for example [LBE Privacy Guard](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.lbe.security.lite)

**NOTE:** This program doesn't work with Android 'Jelly Bean' at the moment

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow. As far as I know, what you want to do is not possible without rooting your phone.

This site is a Q&A-site for **specific** programming questions. A suggestion is that you try it out for yourself, and when you've stumbled upon a specific problem with your **code** you can ask a question here. That way you'll have a much easier time getting answers! Good luck!

Comment: One would think that it is certainly not within the purpose of an *answer* to condescend to the questioner on how to use StackOverflow...

Comment: I don't see how the addition to my answer is in any way condescending! The user asking clearly did not have a good grasp of how the Q&A process here at SO works (random username, low rep). The FAQ and SE blog often encourages helping new users in this way. I could have added it as a comment, but it did not feel necessary at the time. Since you have a higher rep than me you probably know better, so please email me (it's in my profile) if you feel the need to take this discussion further and educate me on netiquette.